# Hierarchy Builder Visulization

Tags: charts, widget, visualization

I'm trying to build an editor for my webapp which has an editable hierarchy and I'm thinking along the lines of some organizational chart visualization (or library) that has an open API to dynamically manipulate the hierarchy. My requirements are that it has to be offline so Google Visualization is out and I've spent some time tweaking with Basic Primitives to find out that it doesn't provide method calls as simple as "get selected item". I've spent a few days searching to no avail so it's quite frustrating. Does anyone know of any simple widgets or libraries out there I could use? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if the following snippet will get you started. Just copy and paste it in HTML file

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>GetOrgChart</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="//www.getorgchart.com/GetOrgChart/getorgchart-1.1/getorgchart.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//www.getorgchart.com/GetOrgChart/getorgchart-1.1/getorgchart.css" />

    <style type='text/css'>
        html, body {margin: 0px;padding: 0px;height: 100%;overflow: hidden;}
        #people {width: 100%;height: 100%;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="peopleTable" style="display: none;">
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>parent id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Lesley Holmes</td>
            <td>CEO</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Colin Patricia</td>
            <td>Manager</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Derek Cork</td>
            <td>Manager</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="people"></div>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $('#people').getOrgChart({
            dataSource: document.getElementById("peopleTable")
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```